# How to escape hyphen(-) in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

My bash script keeps failing because it gets confused at the hyphen:

```
if [ ! -d "$openssl-1.0.1i"]; then ...
```

How do I escape it correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it's in the hyphen? You've forgot a space before `]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the hyphen, you must leave a `space` surrounding each argument in your test construct:

```
if [ ! -d "$openssl-1.0.1i" ]; then ..
```

Why do you have a `$` before openssl?  It's not a variable is it? If not, it should be just:

```
if [ ! -d "openssl-1.0.1i" ]; then ..
```